# Microsoft Graph - Trouble in Contact Folder / Categories API(s)

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-people

There are couple of issues in Graph API for contact folders when used in personal accounts(***@outlook.com)

Issue 1: Contact Folder(Categories) created via graph API is not visible in Outlook UI(even after multiple refreshes over 5 minutes).
-The folder (Folder from API) which was created via API is not visible in Outlook UI (refer image #2) but the getContactFolder API returns the folder (refer image #1)

Issue 2: Above mentioned folder (Folder from API) becomes visible in Outlook UI when a contact is created via graph API inside the folder. (Refer Image #3)

Issue 3: While creating a contact in Outlook UI, the category list is not consistent. Categories created via API are missing. Refer image #4

Issue 4: Change notifications are not consistent for the folders created via API. Microsoft sends the notification only to the contacts created inside the folder via API but not from the UI.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contactfolders/{folderId}/contacts

{"givenName":"Test Contact"}
```

**Steps to reproduce to issue 4**

Step 1:Subscribe for change notifications for the folder created via API.

Step 2: From Outlook UI, create a category with same name as step #1
(refer image #4)

Image 1: Graph API response
[image: API Response]

Image 2: Outlook UI after folder creation
[image: Outlook UI before contact creation]

Image 3: Outlook UI after contact creation in folder via API
[image: Outlook UI after contact creation in folder via API]

Image 4: Category "Folder From API" is not listed during search
[image: Category "Folder From API" is not listed during search]

Comment: For issu#4 : We suspect folder with the same name created via API in step#1 and created via UI in step#2 is considered as separate resource in backend, but it is visible as one category in Outlook UI

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has rolled out a Categories UI for Office 365 / outlook.live.com.  The categories were created, one time, for existent folders; items in those folders still remain in those folders, but now as you create new Contacts within those categories, they are not placed into the folder that initially created the category, but instead are in the main Contacts folder with the category applied.

Office 365 recently received a toggle to toggle between the folder and categories UI, shown below.

[A recent toggle added to switch between categories and folders views of Contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irMj1.png)

By using the folder interface, you can still create contacts in a destination folder.  The categories interface does not provide this functionality.